Flutter: How to Handle Null Context Error When Cancelling User Account Deletion?
Updated code with a new error when press on delete button
    [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.

Here is my whole code
And it points to me this line of code
final provider = Provider.of<DeleteAccountProvider>(context, listen: false);

 class _NavigationDrawerWidgetState extends State<NavigationDrawerWidget> {
  void selectedItem(BuildContext context, int index) {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    if (widget.callBack != null) {
      widget.callBack!();
    }
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ChangePassword()));
        break;
      case 1:
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ContactUs()));
        break;
      case 2:
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const AboutUs()));
        break;
      case 3:
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const AboutUs()));
        break;
      case 4:
        logout();
        break;
      case 5:
        deleteUserAccount(context);
        break;
    }
  }
 Future<void> deleteUserAccount(BuildContext context) async {
    final confirmed = await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return CupertinoAlertDialog(
            title: Text('Confirm Account Deletion'),
            content: Text('Are you sure you want to delete your account? This action cannot be undone.'),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
                child: const Text('Cancel'),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, true),
                child: const Text('Delete'),
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
    if (confirmed != null && confirmed) {
      final provider = Provider.of<DeleteAccountProvider>(context, listen: false);
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      String? userToken = prefs.getString('user_login_token');
      final userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false);
      final email = userProvider.user?.email;
      final success = await provider.deleteAccount(context, userToken ?? '', email ?? '');
      if (success) {
        logout();
      }
    }
  }

  Future<void> logout() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print('Language Code After Logout: ${prefs.getString('languageCode')}');
    }
    if (mounted) {
      context.read<UserProvider>().clearUserData();
    }
    await prefs.remove("user_login_token");
    if (mounted) {
      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => const OnBoardingScreen(),
          ),
          (route) => false);
    }
  }

getting error

Null check operator used on a null value

I'm encountering an issue when trying to delete a user account in my Flutter app. I have a confirmation dialog that asks the user if they really want to delete their account. However, when the user cancels the deletion process by clicking the 'cancel' button on the dialog, I get an error Null check operator used on a null value. I think the context might be null here.
I understand that this type of question has been asked before, but I've been struggling to resolve this error since yesterday. Could someone please provide guidance on how to handle this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here is my code
    Future<void> deleteUserAccount(BuildContext context) async {
    final confirmed = await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) {
          return CupertinoAlertDialog(
            title: Text('Confirm Account Deletion'),
            content: Text('Are you sure you want to delete your account? This action cannot be undone.'),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
                child: const Text('Cancel'),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, true),
                child: const Text('Delete'),
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
    if (confirmed != null && confirmed) {
      final provider = Provider.of<DeleteAccountProvider>(context, listen: false);
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      String? userToken = prefs.getString('user_login_token');
      final userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false);
      final email = userProvider.user?.email;
      final success = await provider.deleteAccount(context, userToken ?? '', email ?? '');
      if (success) {
        logout();
      }
    }
  }

  Future<void> logout() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print('Language Code After Logout: ${prefs.getString('languageCode')}');
    }
    if (mounted) {
      context.read<UserProvider>().clearUserData();
    }
    await prefs.remove("user_login_token");
    if (mounted) {
      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => const OnBoardingScreen(),
          ),
          (route) => false);
    }
  }

Here is the error
    ======== Exception caught by gesture ===============================================================
The following _TypeError was thrown while handling a gesture:
Null check operator used on a null value

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      StatefulElement.state (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5599:44)
#1      Navigator.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2683:47)
#2      Navigator.pop (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2573:15)
#3      _NavigationDrawerWidgetState.deleteUserAccount.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:the_link/widget/navigation_drawer_widget.dart:79:44)
#4      _InkResponseState.handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1183:21)
#5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:315:24)
#6      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:652:11)
#7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:309:5)
#8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:279:7)
#9      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:167:27)
#10     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:499:20)
#11     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:475:22)
#12     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:430:11)
#13     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:420:7)
#14     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:383:5)
#15     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:330:7)
#16     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:299:9)
#17     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:328:13)
#18     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:429:7)
#19     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:262:31)
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#8ddf2
  debugOwner: GestureDetector
  state: ready
  won arena
  finalPosition: Offset(121.3, 501.3)
  finalLocalPosition: Offset(59.8, 23.7)
  button: 1
  sent tap down


Try and add more info. What line number, is generating that null check exception?

Navigator.pop(context, false), on this line

I suspect that the problem is that you ignored a variable binding.  You have:
await showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (_) { .... 

I think you should have:
await showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) { .... 

Right now you're using the first context when you do your Navigator.pop(context, false) and I suspect you shouldn't - you should be using the context in the builder function.

now when I click on Delete it give me error
Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe. At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable. To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.

Again, which line generated that?  Make it easier for folk to help by adding as much info as possible.

final provider = Provider.of<DeleteAccountProvider>(context, listen: false);

kindly check now my updated code, thanks

Hi bro I am still waiting for your answer.Thanks
